# Google's browser console has a Chinese encoding error

Tags: csv, d3.js, encoding

encoding problem:

[image: console]

The code:

```
 d3.dsv(',','22.csv', function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            return {
                dp: d.dp订单号,
            };

        }).then(function (data) {
            // console.log(data); // Array(5)
            render(data);
        });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: can you see the link of console? that  is a picture that can show the problem and i don't know how to express

Comment: this is the picture :[links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP4pU.png). i put it on the question when i asked question.but i can't access it

Comment: [link](https://github.com/picturetxl/problem)